# Pip: Specifying minor version

Tags: python, pip, distribute

In my `requirements.txt` file I want to specify that my app needs Django version 1.3.x. That is, either 1.3.0, or 1.3.1, or 1.3.2, etc. (When these come out.) But not 1.4, when it comes out.

What's the syntax for this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to [Ian Bicking](http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/msg/123b47b6e181ff9f):

```
Django>=1.3,<1.4
```

However, it's [apparently safer to do](http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/msg/07d88e8408fd86d7):

```
Django>=1.3,<1.3.99
```

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but beware that if you want to automatically upgrade Django when a new version comes out on PyPI, you should call pip with the  --upgrade flag, like this: `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`

Comment: What happens if you (hypothetically) had Django `v1.3.100` or later?

Comment: You can use `~=1.3.0` to get the latest patch version, see https://nok.github.io/pipdev?spec=~=1.3.0&vers=1.3.9999 .

Answer (score 2):

> my app needs Django version 1.3.x

In your case, use one of:

---

### Compatible release

```
Django~=1.3.0
```

Ref: [PEP 440 Compatible release](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#compatible-release)

---

### Version matching

```
Django==1.3.*
```

Ref: [PEP 440 Version matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#version-matching)

---

### Ordered comparison

```
Django>=1.3,<1.4
```

Note: ordered operators work for your case after the change introduced in [this commit in 2015](https://github.com/python/peps/commit/c4904f1ae8f5bc14288a08293ea45225a3ac5472)

Ref: [PEP 440 Inclusive ordered comparison](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#inclusive-ordered-comparison)

Ref: [PEP 440 Exclusive ordered comparison](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#exclusive-ordered-comparison)

---